# C# string to necessary type conversion

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, type-conversion, typeof, dynamictype

I have following situation. Lets say i receive list of string values. I have to assign those values to specific type properties in Model.
Model example:

```
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Date { get; set; }
```

There is no problem in type conversion as i get array of property types with System.reflection and use Convert.ChangeType(string value, type).
However, i can't assignt Convert.ChangeType results to model properties because it returns object not my desired type of value.
A short example of my problem:

```
string s1 = "1";
string s2= "11-JUN-2015";
PropertyInfo[] matDetailsProperties = Model.GetType().GetProperties();
List<Type> types = new List<Type>();
        foreach(var item in Model)
        {
            types.Add(item.PropertyType);
        }

Model.ID = Convert.ChangeType(s1, types[0]);
Model.Date = Convert.ChangeType(s2, types[1]);
```

This does not work as Convert.ChangeType returns object and i can't just use (dateTime)Convert.ChangeType(...), that's "dirty code" as i have model with 17 properties with different types. It would be perfect if i could use (Type[0])Convert.ChangeType(...) but it is not possible in C#

Comment: This seems like a really weird thing to be doing - can you provide some context?

Comment: How does you code know to assign `s2`, of runtime type `types[1]` to a property called `Date`, but *not* know that `Date` is of type `DateTime?` (and thus, `types[1]` seems to be redundant)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, his code does know it. The OP unfortunately feels that just writing out a simple model population function is "dirty" code and he wants some way of creating it via reflection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use reflection. How about something like this?

```
var prop = Model.GetType().GetProperty("ID");
var propValue = Convert.ChangeType(s1, types[0]);
if (prop != null && prop.CanWrite)
{
    prop.SetValue(Model, propValue, null);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked (assigning value with reflection), you DA MVP.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to use `Convert.ChangeType`. Just use the existing parsers inside a function to create your model in a simple-to-follow fashion:

```
private static Model PopulateModel(IEnumerable<string> rawData)
{
    return new Model
    {
        ID = int.Parse(rawData[0]),
        Date = DateTime.Parse(rawData[1]),
        ...
    };
}
```

Comment: You did not get it, i have 17 properties, which means, there would be 17 lines with dirty code where i write
    int.Parse, date.Parse etc

Comment: @ArvilsM, oh but I do get it. Rather than try to come up with some "clever" trick of reflection, casting, arrays of types etc (which makes for every hard to read code), just have 17 lines in a function that explicitly converts each type. It's simple, easy to read and easy to maintain. You have a very odd definition of dirty" code as it's actually a very clean solution.

Answer (score 0):

instead of Parse i'll suggest you use `TryParse(string, out DateTime)`

```
int tempId=default(int);
DateTime tempDate=DateTime.Min;

int.TryParse(s1,out tempId);
DateTime.TryParse(s2,out tempDate);

Model.ID = tempId;
Model.Date = tempDate;
```

Comment: You don't need to assign `tempId` and `tempDate` since the `out` call will **definitely** set it.